# Multiple function forms in template pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I wanted to ask what is the best way to implement template pattern in which template method can have multiple forms (I guess it wouldn't be template pattern then).

Let's say I have an abstract class with one abstract method and few concrete methods:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any


class TemplateClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self, my_client):
        self.client = my_client

    def run(self) -> Any:
        self._step1()
        self._step2()
        self._step3()
        self.execute_specific_logic()

    @abstractmethod
    def _execute_specific_logic(self) -> Any:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _step1(self):
        pass
    
    def _step2(self):
        pass

    def _step3(self):
        pass
```

And I want to create about 10 classes that will inherit `TemplateClass`, but:

- 7 of them should have `run` method with all steps
- 2 of them should have `run` method only with _step2 and _step3
- 1 of them should have `run` method only with _step1

I was wondering about different ways to implement such logic:

- implementing different `run` methods for every case - `run`, `run_without_step1`, `run_without_step2_and_step3`
- adding flag argument to `run` method such as `is_step_x_required` with `True` as default and passing `Flase` in subclass method when needed
- overwriting in `run` method in subclasses when needed
- using some kind of mixin class?

I would really appreciate any advice on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

All the techniques you list are reasonable. My first inclination was towards the "least" amount of boilerplate:

```
class Stepper(ABC):
    def __init__(self, run_steps):
        self._run_steps = run_steps
        self._steps = [self._step1, self._step2, self._step3]

    def run(self):
        for step in self._run_steps:
            self._steps[i - 1]()


class Only23Stepper(Stepper):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(run_steps=[2, 3])
```

For more flexibility, but more boilerplate, one may override `run()` to explicitly specify the steps.

However, we may want to express this in a different way than with classes. It is well known that [inheritance is evil](https://www.google.com/search?q=inheritance+is+evil). It is possible that the reason we're running into design issues and potential inflexibility is that this could be expressed in a simpler way using plain old functions.